# compare between two queue list

Tags: java

I have two queue `list`s and I want to check if `q2` is reverse for `q1`.

This is my code.

```
public static boolean reverse ( LinkedQueue q1, LinkedQueue q2 ) {             
    for ( int i = 0; i < q1.length() ; i ++)

    if ( q1.serve ()  == q2.gettail().getdata() ) {
        q1.enqueue(q1.serve ());
        return true ;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I just check if the head of q1 equal the tail of q2 but my problem is I want to check for all elements that they are equal and I don't know how.

Comment: Which implementation of `LinkedQueue` are you using?

Comment: protip: Post formatted code. Format it in your IDE or using some online java formatter.

Comment: It is most likely that your best option is to convert one of those queues into an `ArrayList` and use `ListIterator.hasPrevious` on that while using the default iterator on the other one.

Comment: i can't use previous  and i have to stuck with linked list queue because this is what the question in my homework require ! i can only use head , tail , next , data , enqueue and serve methods  . thank you for your help i really appetite it.

Answer (score 0):

The way one normally approaches it is to return `true` in the end. Iterate through and only return `false` if `i+n i+length-n`.

**Assuming** everything else is working it will be like this.

```
public static boolean reverse ( LinkedQueue q1, LinkedQueue q2 ) {             
    for ( int i = 0; i < q1.length() ; i ++) {
        if ( q1.serve ()  == q2.gettail().getdata() ) {
            q1.enqueue(q1.serve ());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

*Note: You also missed curly brackets around your `for`.*

Comment: Cool, the algorithm to compare if sequences match in reverse order modifies the underlying sequences. This is going to write history in algorithm development. I must admit that the question itself suffers from this genius idea.